# changing text fields color using setInterval;

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change a text fields background color when I click a button and the blinking should stop after the certain period of time/

I tried experimenting with setInterval with a setTimeout inside it and here is the result:

```js
var interval;
function myFunction2(){
 interval = setInterval(function(){myFunction()}, 500);
}
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("blink");
 x.style.backgroundColor = x.style.backgroundColor == "white" ? "blue" : "white";
 setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(interval);}, 1500);
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>blink</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="text" id="blink" value="blinking!"  style="background: white;">
  <button type="button" id="blinkbtn" onclick="myFunction2();">click!</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

There are 2 issues in this code though sometimes the background get stuck on the color blue and I dont want that. The second problem is after the first run of the functions(when the button is pressed)you need to  double click the button to run the functions again.

Comment: It isn’t java. It’s is JavaScript

Comment: "Java (not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript or JS)" wrong tag, an usual problem here even if it's often soon corrected

Comment: sorry for the confusion i changed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You where setting the timeout 3 times (each time the interval function was called)

this version solves your issues:

```js
var interval, timeout;
var x = document.getElementById("blink");
function clear(){
  if(interval){
    clearInterval(interval); 
    console.log("clear interval");
  }
  if(timeout){
    clearInterval(timeout); 
    console.log("clear timeout");
    x.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
}

function myFunction2(){
  clear();
 interval = setInterval(myFunction, 500);
  timeout = setTimeout(clear, 2050); //4x500 + a little delay to ensure the 4 times run
}
function myFunction() {
 x.style.backgroundColor = x.style.backgroundColor == "white" ? "blue" : "white";
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>blink</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="text" id="blink" value="blinking!"  style="background: white;">
  <button type="button" id="blinkbtn" onclick="myFunction2();">click!</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `css` for the blinking [animation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) and use javascript's [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) to add the class `.blink` and remove it after `x` seconds :

```js
function myFunction2() {
  const x = document.getElementById("blink")
  x.classList.add('blink')
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    x.classList.remove('blink')
  }, 1000)
  
}
```

```css
.blink {
  animation: blink .1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from {
    background: #fff;
  }
  to {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="blink" value="blinking!" style="background: white;">
<button type="button" id="blinkbtn" onclick="myFunction2();">click!</button>
```